# show/hide button when focus the list item in android listview

Tags: android, show-hide, android-button, listadapter

Many list items are listed in my listview.

In that list item having 2 buttons and one textview.

Here i have using following code. Now my list showing the edit/delete button.If I have to focus which list item means that item alone have to show edit/delete button.other list item don't need to show the edit/delete button.

How can i do ? Please check it and give me a idea to implement this part ?

```
 stafflist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Button bPrevious = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.view_staff);
                    bPrevious.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Button bPlaying = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_staff);
                bPlaying.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Now if i have selected any item from that list means it's showing the edit/delete button. after that i have selected any other item from list means that item also showing the edit/delete button with this previous selected  item also showing the edit/delete button.

But i want to show the current selected item only need to show edit/delete button ?

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manager_list_staff, null);
    TextView staffname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.my_staffname);
    TextView staff_empcode = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.my_staffempcode);
    LinearLayout editdelete = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.edit_delete);
    final Button edit_staff = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.view_staff); 
    final Button delete_staff = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.delete_staff);
    HashMap<String, String> Order = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Order = data.get(position);
    int temp = parent.getId()+1;
    staff_id.setText(Order.get(Manager_List_Staff.TAG_STAFF_ID));
```

Comment: means after clicking on list item you want to show edit/delete button??

Comment: use Contextual Action Bar with edit and delete button

Comment: i want to show the current selected item alone need to show edit/delete button ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the below code and its working, you could check with your requirement. The **notifyDataSetChanged()** method is used to tell the adapter that the arraylist values are changed so please reload the list so now we got the selected item and we will keep it's VISIBLE state to true and others to GONE.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{

ListView listview;
testAdapter adp;
ArrayList<String> testvalues=new ArrayList<String>();
public static int selectedValue=-1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);       

    testvalues.add("India");
    testvalues.add("USA");
    testvalues.add("Australia");

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    adp=new testAdapter();

    listview.setAdapter(adp);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
{
    Button bPrevious = (Button)arg1.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bPrevious.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Button bPlaying = (Button)arg1.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    bPlaying.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    selectedValue=arg2;
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class testAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{           
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return testvalues.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return testvalues.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testing, null);
        TextView staffname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);        

        final Button edit_staff = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        final Button delete_staff = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        staffname.setText(testvalues.get(position));
        if(selectedValue==position && selectedValue!=-1)
        {
            edit_staff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            delete_staff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            edit_staff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            delete_staff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return vi;
    }

}

}
```

**Main Activity XML Layout File (activity_main.xml)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Inflate XML Layout File (testing.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it means : Now if i have selected any item from that list means it's showing the edit/delete button. after that i have selected any other item from list means that item also showing the edit/delete button with this previous selected item also showing the edit/delete button.

But i want to show the current selected item only need to show edit/delete button ?

Comment: @user2218667 I have updated the answer, so now you could check with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use member variable to store the button. In my case, I'm using Layout to display some text along with button. So I'm changing the view of the inner layout of list item.

```
View hiddenLayout;
```

Attach listener to the listView. Before hiding the view / layout, verify if it is visible or not.

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                if(hiddenLayout != null && hiddenLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                hiddenLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.myTripBbuttonLayout);
                hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onClickItem listener you need to define and find your button. Here is an example:

```
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int btnStart = R.id.btnStart;
        int btnDelete = R.id.btnDelete;
        //here set all button in item invisible
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(btnStart).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(btnDelete).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        //but here we set for selected item buttons visible, and change background        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_selected_nav_drawer));
        view.findViewById(btnStart).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.findViewById(btnDelete).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Also notice View view is same as parent.getChildAt(position);